# I can't use the abp command in ubuntu, You must install .NET to run this application

Tags: ubuntu, command, abp

I can't use abp in the command line in ubuntu, i have this problem.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfbB1.png)

I've already tried reinstalling everything, and even formatting my Ubuntu, but I can't use the 'abp' command.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this problem does not seem to be related to abp. Microsoft has a solution for this issue:

If you wish, you can review the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos) here.

[image]